# Arch Linux RAID working, but won't mount on bootup. Bootup broken now

Tags: arch-linux, boot, fstab, raid, software-raid

I have a headless server running Arch and sharing a software RAID.

After what looked to be a successful system upgrade, bootup now fails due to a timeout when trying to load the RAID. I get the message:

"[TIME] Timed out waiting for device /dev/[UUID of RAID]"

After logging into maintenance mode and removing the RAID from my fstab, the system boots up fine.

Now I can log in as a normal user, **mount the RAID manually** (i.e. "sudo mount /dev/md0 [mountpoint]"), and **it works**. I'm able to share the files, run services that interact w/ the RAID volume, etc.. Everything runs as normal.

But if I add the RAID back into fstab, and reboot, bootup breaks with the same timeout message.

I've double-checked the UUID hasn't changed, and also tried adding it to fstab using the name (/dev/md0) instead just as a test. Same results.

Any help fixing this, so the RAID mounts automatically on boot as before, is hugely appreciated!

**

More info as requested:

1. fstab... *(details x'd out)*

ORIGINAL (worked for years but no longer, times out on boot):

```
# System (/dev/sdxx)
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx       /               ext4            rw,relatime     0 1
# Share (RAID)
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx       /mnt/xxxxx      ext4            defaults        0 2
```

CURRENT (workaround -- this allows for boot, then I have to mount the RAID manually):

```
# System Partition (/dev/sdxx)
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx       /               ext4            rw,relatime     0 1
# Share (RAID)
#/dev/xxx                               /mnt/xxxxx      ext4            defaults        0 2
```

Results of ls -al /etc/ | grep fstab:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    322 Mar 11 04:59 fstab
```

Results of udevadm info /dev/xxx:

```
P: /devices/virtual/block/xxx
M: xxx
R: 0
U: block
T: disk
D: b 9:0
N: xxx
L: 100
S: disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
S: disk/by-id/md-uuid-xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
S: disk/by-label/media
S: disk/by-id/md-name-marty:0
S: xx/x
Q: 7
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/md0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/md0
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: DISKSEQ=7
E: MAJOR=9
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=17956341
E: ID_IGNORE_DISKSEQ=1
E: MD_LEVEL=raid0
E: MD_DEVICES=4
E: MD_METADATA=1.2
E: MD_UUID=xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
E: MD_DEVNAME=0
E: MD_NAME=marty:0
E: ID_FS_LABEL=media
E: ID_FS_LABEL_ENC=media
E: ID_FS_UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
E: ID_FS_VERSION=1.0
E: ID_FS_BLOCKSIZE=4096
E: ID_FS_LASTBLOCK=4883637248
E: ID_FS_SIZE=2411192123392
E: ID_FS_TYPE=ext4
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-xxxxx>
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:systemd:
```

...Thanks again!

Comment: Can you post your fstab (with UUIDs masked) as well as the the results of 'ls -al /etc/ | grep fstab'

Comment: Added requested info to post. Thank you!

Comment: What does `udevadm info` show for the RAID device?

Comment: Added. Thank you!